# How to pass axios response data to vue 3 using axios all

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to do multiple request with axios and save the response in a vue 3 prop. I know don't mutate props, but that's an other discussion. Because `translation` is an object (variable is passed by reference), mutating it should be possible here.

As I understood it correctly `axios.all()` makes multiple async requests at once. The code here works correctly, the axios request are made successfully and I can `console.log(response.data)` them within the `then()` code. So far so good.

What absolutely doesn't work is this line: `this.translation[Object.keys(response.data)[index]] = response.data;` - The prop `translation` won't be mutated and I don't get any errors in the console, but as I wrote the text "submitted all axois calls" appears in the console.

If I mutate the prop **before** the axios call, e.g. `this.translation["foo"] = { bar: "foo" }` it works.

What am I doing here wrong? How can I pass the data here from the axios-response to the prop variable `translation`?

```
export default {
  props: {
    marketplaces: Object,
    translation: Object,
  } 
}
```

```
let requests = [axios1, axios2, ...]

axios
    .all(requests)
    .then(
        axios.spread((...responses) => {
            responses.forEach((response, index) => {
                this.translation[Object.keys(response.data)[index]] = response.data;
            });
            console.log("submitted all axios calls");
        })
    )
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("ERRRR:: ", error.response.data);
    });
```

Comment: FWIW, all and spread are obsolete. These features exist in JS for a long time.

Comment: Do you have any hint, how to use multiple requests in 2021?

Answer (score 0):

So, I have now changed to code like the newest axios docs are showing for multiple post request and have changed this line `.then((results) => {` so now `this` is scoped correctly.

```
export default {
  props: {
    marketplaces: Object,
    translation: Object,
  } 
}

let requests = [axios1, axios2, ...]

Promise.all(requests)
.then((results) => {
  results.forEach((result, index) => {
    // I get the CORRECT result here
    console.log("BEFORE:");
    console.log(this.translation);

    this.translation[Object.keys(result.data)[index]] = result.data;

    console.log("AFTER:");
    console.log(this.translation);
  });
})
```

I put a `console.log` **BEFORE** and **AFTER** mutating the object `this.translation` and indeed, the objects seems to be mutated in console.log but **not** in the Vue-Dev-Tools. So I have to change something else, has it something to do with the `mounted()` thing in Vue?

Comment: Do I have to bind ```this``` anywhere here within the axios call?

Comment: Promise.all, etc is the way this should be done. Are you saying that you put this outside the component? This is a mistake then. It should be done inside.

Comment: *If I put a block below export (so before axios) like this: this.translation["foo"] = { bar: "foo" } it works* - this is a mistake, `this` is module object there.

Comment: I put my answer below.

Comment: Changing the function on `.then(function` after the Promise.all to an arrow function doens't solve the scope issue of `this`?

Comment: Also, why do it in the root of script instead of a lifecycle hook of the Vue component, like created or mounted?

Comment: I have edited the code and all my comments above, shortified: the arrow => has changed the scope, I put console.log before and after mutating the object. In console.log it seems to be mutating but not in Vue-Dev-Tools. Does it have something to do with created() or mounted()?

Comment: I've just also tried to access ```$props``` directly: ```$props.translation[Object.keys(result.data)[index]] = result.data[Object.keys(result.data)[index]];``` but then I get the error $props is not defined. So, it's a scoping problem? I'm really stucked more than 2 days on this problem right now :-(

Comment: Maybe it will help, if I insert here the whole <script> code. I will post it as answer below.

Comment: Consider posting intermediate results to the question instead of an answer. It cannot be qualified as an answer if it doesn't answer the question yet. Yes, it has direct connection to created or mounted. If the code is supposed to run once per component instance, it should be located in mounted. It's incorrect to put the code that affects a component outside it.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default {
  // Persistent Layout for Menu and Header
  layout: (h, page) => h(Layout, [page]),
  layout: BreezeAuthenticatedLayout,

  components: {
    BreezeAuthenticatedLayout,
    FormButton,
    FormInput,
    FormSelect,
    FormRadio,
    MarketplaceForm,
  },

  setup() {
    const form = useForm({
      asin: "1234567890", //null,
      sourceMarketplace: "de", //null,
      formality: "default",
    });

    return { form };
  },
  props: {
    marketplaces: Object,
    translation: Object,
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      this.form.post(
        "/translation/fetch-listing",
        {
          onSuccess: (page) => {
            console.warn("Now translate:");
            this.translateAll();
          },
        }
      );
    },
    translateAll() {
      let requests = [];
      Object.keys(this.marketplaces).forEach((value, index) => {
        if (this.form.sourceMarketplace === value) return;

        let postData = {
          sourceMarketplace: this.form.sourceMarketplace,
          targetMarketplace: value,
          formality: this.form.formality,
          translation: this.translation,
        };

        let newPromise = axios({
          method: "post",
          url: "/translation/translate",
          data: postData,
        });

        requests.push(newPromise);
      });

      Promise.all(requests)
        .then((results) => {
          results.forEach((result, index) => {
            console.log(index);
            console.log("translation before: ");
            console.log(this.translation);
            this.translation[Object.keys(result.data)[index]] =
              result.data[Object.keys(result.data)[index]];
            console.log("translation after: ");
            console.log(this.translation);
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Axios error: ");
          console.error(error);
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```